# ActiveRecord wrong columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create a new object that is related to two other models but I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

The model is:

## vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  
  belongs_to :solution
  belongs_to :user
  
end
```

(The solution and user model both have `has_many :votes` on their side.

In my solutions controller I'm doing this:

```
  def process_vote
    solution = Solution.find(params[:id])
    vote = Vote.where(:user => current_user, :solution => solution)
    if(vote.count == 0)
      newvote = Vote.new
      newvote.user = current_user
      newvote.positive = true
      newvote.solution = solution
      newvote.save
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render :nothing => true
      }
    end
  end
```

The query generated by ActiveRecord is looking for the wrong columns though, this is what console shows when I call the `process_vote` method:

```
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes` WHERE `votes`.`user` = 2 AND `votes`.`solution` = 5

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'votes.user' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes`  WHERE `votes`.`user` = 2 AND `votes`.`solution` = 5
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'votes.user' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes`  WHERE `votes`.`user` = 2 AND `votes`.`solution` = 5):
  app/controllers/solutions_controller.rb:74:in `process_vote'
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? It seems to me that the relations are set up fine. The actual column names are `user_id` and `solution_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Seems like you should not get full solution instance from the DB. Solution ID from params should be enough.
2. Do not use association names in the `where`. Use ID's

So your action should looks like this:

```rb
def process_vote
  current_user.votes << Vote.new(:positive => true, solution_id => params[:id]) if current_user.votes.where(:solution_id => params[:id]).count == 0
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
      render :nothing => true
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. One more question: I was also trying to delete the vote if there was already one from the `current_user` for that particular solution. Is that possible with your code? There isn't really a way to reference it, right? So I could do something like `vote.destroy`?

Comment: You can update existed instance instead of deleting and creating the new one. But this time you should use variable.

Comment: For example `vote = current_user.votes.where(:solution_id => params[:id]) || current_user.votes.build(:solution_id => params[:id])` then set additional parameters and save.

Answer (score 3):

```
vote = Vote.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :solution_id => solution.id)
```

Comment: I had tried this, and it does work indeed, but still, shouldn't ActiveRecord detect the relations inside the where clause?

Comment: I'm not sure about this because I have never used it that way. I just looked at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database and I can not find there any example with relation. So maybe it is not possible.